# Unzip a password protected file in vbsript

Tags: vbscript, zip

i am facing a trouble here,Could you please tell me how to unzip a password protected  field in vbscript?
I have a code which runs perfectly,but it asking password each time when it runs

```
pathToZipFile="C:\folder.zip" 
extractTo="C:\" 
set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
set filesInzip=sa.NameSpace(pathToZipFile).items 
sa.NameSpace(extractTo).CopyHere(filesInzip)
```

I need a code which will not ask password in run,Please help,Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the `Shell.Application` object doesn't support providing a password. Try [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) instead:

```
pass    = "..."
zipfile = "your.zip"

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "7za.exe x -p" & pass & " " & zipfile, 0, True
```

If necessary add the path to `7za.exe` and/or `file.zip`. If the path contains spaces, you'll also need to put double quotes around it, e.g. like this:

```
Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function

zipfile = qq("C:\path\with spaces\to\your.zip")
```