# VBA Unzip passwort protected ZIP file

Tags: excel, vba, zip

I have following VBA Code to Unzip files and it works perfectly. However I have received a password protected ZIP file which I want to open (I got the password):

```
Sub UnzipAFile(zippedFileFullName As Variant, unzipToPath As Variant)
Dim ShellApp As Object
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ShellApp.Namespace(unzipToPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items
MsgBox ("Unzipped File")
End Sub
```

I am using a Call Function to in my main methode which is:

```
Call UnzipAFile("C:\path\Videos\windows.zip", "C:\path\Videos\")
```

How can I implement the password to my code?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Plenty of previous question here on that topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+unzip+password+protected+files+site:stackoverflow.com   For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327217/unzip-a-password-protected-file-in-vbsript  You can't use your current approach: you will need to use a different methos such a 7-Zip/WinZip etc and call that using a command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was really hoping there would be a different way to handle this problem unless using 7Zip or WinZip. I do not know if there is 7Zip or WinZip installed on the machine where the script will be executed.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you doing and why are you using Excel for it?